# Redirection doesn't work in shell:: ls: cannot access >: No such file or directory

Tags: c, file, shell, fork, io-redirection

I don't know why redirection doesn't work in the shell I have written. Here's my code"

```
int i;     
     for (i=1; !args[i];i++)
         {
           if (args[i]== ">")
             {
               printf("argv[i] %s %d \n", args[i], i);
               int out; 
              // out = open("out", O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWUSR);
                out=open("out", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);


                int fdl=dup2(out,1);        
                close(out);   
                execvp(args[0],args);
             }

         }
```

Also here's the error I receive :

```
mysh> ls
basic_shell    basic_shell.c~    fork    fork_2  fork_cp.c
basic_shell.c  basic_shell_OK.c  fork_1  fork.c
mysh> ls > file
ls: cannot access >: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access file: No such file or directory
```

Please let me know what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If `args` is an array of `char*`, then this condition

```
if (args[i]== ">")
```

does not do what you think it does. It compares the *pointers* and not what they point to. To compare string you have to use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).